# Safe way of force downcasting

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a "safe" way to write this that protects against runtime errors?

```
for posts in resultsArray as! [AnyObject] {
    //do stuff
}
```

I feel like an if-let or guard statement would work here, I'm not sure how to make that work with a for-in loop .

Comment: What type has `resultsArray`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `as` used for upcasting and type casting to bridged type
- `as?` used for safe casting, return nil if failed
- `as!` used to force casting, crash if failed

**Safe Downcasting**

```
for posts in resultsArray as? [AnyObject] {
    //do stuff
}
```

`posts` will be a variable of type AnyObject?. If the underlying type is something other than it will harmlessly just assign `nil`.

---

**Unsafe Downcasting**

```
for posts in resultsArray as! [AnyObject] {
    //do stuff
}
```

This too will result in posts being of type AnyObject?, but it will `crash` if the underlying type is something else.

[Reference](http://www.fantageek.com/blog/2015/09/23/type-casting-in-swift/)

Comment: In the "Unsafe Downcasting" example, `posts` has the type `AnyObject`,  not `AnyObject?`. – The "Safe Downcasting" example somehow does not compile for me: *"value of optional type '[AnyObject]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"*

Answer (score 1):

You can do the casting inside the for-in-loop with `as?`.

```
for result in resultsArray {
   if let post = result as? AnyObject {
      //do stuff
   } else {
      //do other stuff
   }
}
```

This way you can choose what happens if the cast fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting `resultsArray` to `[AnyObject]`? Wouldn't it better to cast it to the correct type?

So given

```
class Post { }
let resultsArray: Any = [Post(), Post()]
```

You can write this

```
func doSomething(resultsArray: Any) {
    guard let posts = resultsArray as? [Post] else { return }
    for post in posts  {
        print(post)
    }
}
```